# Select only first record within a time interval

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeviceLogs](
    [DeviceLogId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    [UserId] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LogDate] [datetime2](0) NULL,
)
GO
```

**Data Sample**

```
   1     1    2013-05-29 11:05:15   //accepted (its the first occurance for userid 1)
   2     1    2013-05-29 11:05:20   //discarded (within 5 mins from 1st record)
   3     1    2013-05-29 11:07:56   //discarded (within 5 mins from 1st record)
   4     1    2013-05-29 11:11:15   //accepted (after 5 mins from 1st occurance)
   5     2    2013-05-29 11:06:05   //accepted (its the first occurance for userid 2)
   6     2    2013-05-29 11:07:18   //discarded (within 5 mins from 1st record)
   7     2    2013-05-29 11:09:38   //discarded (within 5 mins from 1st record)
   8     2    2013-05-29 11:12:15   //accepted (after 5 mins from 1st occurance)
```

I want to select only records which have occured after 5 mins from previous selected record and including the first record within the dataset

**Desired output is**

```
 1     1     2013-05-29 11:05:15   
 4     1     2013-05-29 11:11:15
 5     2     2013-05-29 11:06:05 
 8     2     2013-05-29 11:12:15
```

I am trying GroupBy but doesn't give date

```
db.DeviceLogs.GroupBy(g=>new {g.LogDate.Year, 
                              g.LogDate.Month, 
                              g.LogDate.Day, 
                              g.LogDate.Hour, 
                              g.LogDate.Minutes, 
                              g.UserID})
             .Select(s=>new {UserID=s.Key.UserID, s.???});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in LINQ-to-SQL. You could do it in LINQ-to-objects by abusing `GroupBy` with a custom comparison, or with a custom LINQ-like method (although that's not really using LINQ anymore).

Comment: I need a bit of clarification. Will all entries after five minutes be included or, does the sampling continue? If it continues, do the five minute windows remain based on the first entry or, does each window start from the last acceptee?

Comment: @Jodrell: Yes only the Window is 5 minutes, the entries are months and year long. Secondly five minute window remain based on the first entry in the dataset of that specific user.

Comment: @Marshal, restablished may answer to group into tumbling five minute windows based on the first event.

Comment: Your line `only records which have occured after 5 mins from previous selected record` seems to be at odds with `five minute window remain based on the first entry`.

Comment: @Rawling: Edited that part for clarification. I knew it would be difficult to explain so I also included the `Desired Output`

Comment: We really need more data to get what you mean. For example, if you have a record at 0:00, a record at 0:07, and a record at 0:11 (all for the same ID), do you (a) define your windows as 0-5, 5-10 and 10-15 and thus return all three records as they all lie in separate windows, or do you (b) return 0:00, 0:07 (because 7-0 > 5) but not 0:11 (because 11-7 < 5)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result =
    from log in db.DeviceLogs
    let byId = 
        db.DeviceLogs.Where(item => item.UserId == log.UserId)
    let first =
        byId.First(item => item.LogDate == byId.Min(min => min.LogDate))
    where 
        log.Equals(first) || (log.LogDate - first.LogDate).Minutes > 5
    select log;
```

Comment: 1 sec, pls. Seems that the error is that you are comparing with MinimumDate element among ALL records, while you should compare with user-specific minimum. Pls, see my answer.

Comment: `.Where(item => item.UserId == log.UserId)` constraints the searched set to the user :)

Comment: That's a changed version of your answer with an output in linqpad, though I don't deny your answer was a basis. And I did give you an upvote

Comment: `db.DeviceLogs.Min(min => min.LogDate)` is not constrained, that's just the very minimum date

Comment: You barely do the same as me and just put the id filtering thing in an extra variable... your answer does originaly the same as mine.

Comment: Okay, then change your answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: @JanP. Thank you for answer.. will try and get back to it.

Comment: @JanP. It works well with `db.DeviceLogs` but it fails if I work with `List<DeviceLogs>`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, how about.

```
var firstDates = db.DeviceLogs.GroupBy(d => d.UserId).ToDictionary(
    g => g.Key,
    g => g.OrderBy(d => d.LogDate).First().LogDate);

db.DeviceLogs.GroupBy(g => new
  {
    v = Math.Floor(SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute(firstDates[d.UserId], g.LogDate) / 5),
    u = g.UserID
  }).Select(s => s.OrderBy(s => s.LogDate).First());
```

I'm not sure you can use linq to SQL to do this in one query. There is a potential problem if the number of minutes exceeds the max value of a 32bit integer.

Comment: I've removed my dv as this isn't as egregiously wrong as I thought at first glance, but it will only get the first item per user per absolute minute rather than a first-item-per-user-per-sliding-five-minute-window.

Comment: @Rawling, amended after clarification.

Comment: This gives an error in GroupBy Statement: `Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you an SQL solution:

```
SELECT  [DeviceLogId],[UserId],[LogDate] FROM (
    SELECT *,
          (SELECT top 1 [LogDate] FROM DeviceLogs t2
                      WHERE datediff(minute,t2.logDate,t1.logDate)>5
                      ORDER BY [LogDate] DESC) prev,
          (SELECT TOP 1 [Logdate] FROM DeviceLogs t3 
              WHERE t3.[LogDate]=
                    (SELECT MIN([LogDate])
                     FROM DeviceLogs t4 
                     WHERE t4.[UserId]=t1.[UserId])) first
    FROM DeviceLogs t1 ) tres
WHERE prev IS NOT NULL OR first=logdate
```

See fiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa74e/50

Comment: Thanks voo.. but it is very difficult for me to convert it to LINQ :P

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure you can do this with a single LINQ statement, as you need to remember the DateTime of the last record yielded.
You can use an iterator block like so:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan MinimumTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,5,0);

IEnumerable<Record> getSparseRecords(IEnumerable<Record> allRecords)
{
    DateTime previous = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach(var record in allRecords)
    {
        TimeSpan dif = record.DateTime - previous;
        if (dif >= MinimumTimeSpan)
        {
            previous = record.DateTime;
            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

where Record would be a class to represent a single record, which includes a DateTime property of type `DateTime` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)). If your `LogDate` property is of a different type, you might need to change the code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DeviceLog> list = new List<DeviceLog>
            {
                new DeviceLog() { Id = 1, UserId = 1, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:05:15") },
                new DeviceLog() { Id = 2, UserId = 1, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:05:20") },
                new DeviceLog() { Id = 3, UserId = 1, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:07:56") },
                new DeviceLog() { Id = 4, UserId = 1, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:11:15") },

                new DeviceLog() { Id = 5, UserId = 2, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:06:05") },
                new DeviceLog() { Id = 6, UserId = 2, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:07:18") },
                new DeviceLog() { Id = 7, UserId = 2, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:09:38") },
                new DeviceLog() { Id = 8, UserId = 2, LogDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-29 11:12:15") },
            };

        list = list.Where(l => (l.Id == list.Where(g => g.UserId == l.UserId).Min(h => h.Id))
            || (l.LogDate - list.Where(g => g.UserId == l.UserId).OrderBy(m => m.Id).First().LogDate).Minutes > 5 ).ToList();


    }


}

class DeviceLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }

}
```